# Grow up animation using Tweener

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2

(beginner) Take a look at http://teethgrinder.co.uk/open-flash-chart-2/bar-chart-on-show.php and grow-up animation. The code for this animation is (AS2):

```
   mc._yscale= 0; //mc - MovieClip object
   Tweener.addTween(mc, {_yscale:100, time:1.4, transition:"easeoutquint"} );

   //using mc._height gives the same effect
```

And it works fine for simple bars. Problem is, that it doesn't look that good eg. for 3D bars, because it scales the object. What it shoud, it should "reveal"/"uncover" the bar. Is it possible to do it with the Tweener or do I have to do it some other way?

Answer (score 1):

To reveal the bar without scaling it you could put a mask over it and use Tweener to scale the  mask instead of the bar. You should be able to use your existing code by updating the target property (`mc`)to the instance name of the mask.